# Site title in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

Do you know that how to extract the site title from the link in the sharepoint?

Comment: What do you mean by 'from the link in the SharePoint'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [SPWeb class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.aspx) to retrieve [title property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.title.aspx).

Sample code:

```
SPWeb oWebsite = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb("Website_URL");
string siteTitle = oWebSite.Title;
```

Resources:

- [SPWeb Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb_properties.aspx)